# Upgrade to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS from 15.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 16.04

I face this error when trying to upgrade to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS (from 15.10). I confirm that I have a working internet connection. How can I solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: You could try another server, or wait a day, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Go under SystemSettings -> Software&Updates to "Ubuntu Software" tab. Try setting there the in "Download from" field to "Main Server". I had similar problem with my preset server not working always. You can also select the "Other.." option instead of "Main Server". A window will open where you can click on "Select Best Server" and let Ubuntu find the best/closest/fastest option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I tried it and get best server is in Hong Kong, but still face this error. Can you share your selected server ?

Comment: I am using "Main Server" option. It can be some other problem if this does not work.

Comment: waiting for update... are you using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS now ? any problems with current extensions on 15.10 ?