# Enable upgrade options when using installation from DVD?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 16.04

I can not upgrade my system from Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 to 16.04 by Software Updater, then I trying download ISO file and burn to disc.
I can boot to Ubuntu from it and install 16.04, but the option "Upgrade... to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 is disabled"[upgrade to 16.04 is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccX3o.jpg). I want to keep all data (/usr) and installed program on my computer (eg. Skype, VirtualBox...).
What should I do or what is the best option for my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to upgrade from Ubuntu .. try typing in a terminal the following:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

If that doesn't work run

```
update-manager
```

click on Settings

Look for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" and set it so it says "For any new versions"

Then use update-manager to check for updates install any if any new ones show up then check again and it  should come up with the upgrade

Comment: I tried but faced this message: "Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your support ! But with this way, I got this error and posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763505/upgrade-to-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-lts-from-15-10/763570
Do you have any ideas with this error ?